# Why can't I break the loop when typing done in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to exit the loop with done, and not accept non-integers, what am I doing wrong?

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Enter a number or enter done: "))
        if (num % 2) == 0:
            print("Number is Even")
        elif (num % 2) == 1:
            print("Number is Odd")
        else:
            num == 'done'
            break
    except:
            print ('Invalid Input')
print ('Done')
```

Comment: `num` is a number, and can thus never be `"done"`; instead you get "invalid input"

Comment: There's no `if` before `num == 'done'`. Even if the comparison were valid, you're never even testing for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this line here:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number or enter done: "))
```

Will convert your input to an `int`. The string `done` cannot be converted to an `int` and will throw an exception and just straight to your except block instead of your `if .. elif` code.

You might instead try checking for `done` before converting the input to an int:

```
while True:
    try:
        num_str = input("Enter a number or enter done: ")
        if num_str == 'done':
            break

        num = int(num_str)
        if (num % 2) == 0:
            print("Number is Even")
        else:
            print("Number is Odd")

    except:
        print('Invalid Input')

print('Done')
```

Comment: Another issue is that he doesn't check `if num == 'done'`, he just asserts it, so it does nothing anyways.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the input *before* you try to convert it to `int`. A number can never be equal to `'done'`.

There's no need for `elif (num % 2) == 1:`; if a number isn't even, the only other possibility is that it's odd, so you can just use `else:`.

It's also a little better to put the `try:` only around the statement that performs the conversion.

```
while True:
    response = input("Enter a number or enter done: ")
    if response == 'done':
        break;

    try:
        num = int(response)
    except:
        print ('Invalid Input')
        continue

    if (num % 2) == 0:
        print("Number is Even")
    else:
        print("Number is Odd")

print ('Done')
```

Answer (score 1):

When you type `'done'`, your program attemps to cast the string to an `int`. This raises a `ValueError` which is caught. Then the loop starts again.

Since you need to keep your user input to check if it is `'done'` when the `int` cast fails, I suggest you do not rely on a `try-except` block, but use `str.isdigit` instead.

```
while True:
    answer = input("Enter a number or enter done: ")

    if answer.isdigit() and int(answer) % 2 == 0:
        print("Number is Even")

    elif answer.isdigit() and int(answer) % 2 == 1:
        print("Number is Odd")

    elif answer.lower() == 'done':
        break

    else:
        print('Invalid input')

print ('Done')
```

#### Sidenote

If you want to use a `try-except` block, then you should be specific about the exception you want to catch, otherwise you may catch exceptions that would indicate real errors, or even catch a `KeyboardInterrupt` error, that will prevent exiting your program.

```
# Good
try:
    ...
except ValueError:
    ...

# Bad
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```